# Why there are KEYS and ARGV arrays when calling Redis Lua scripts?

Tags: redis

When calling Lua scripts from within Redis, it is possible to pass values in two arrays: KEYS and ARGV. What is the difference? How does Redis treat values in the KEYS array? What if, in my script, I have to use keys dynamically generated at run time?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

All your questions are answered at the [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) page, but since you asked...:

> What is the difference?

`KEYS` is used to pass key names whereas `ARGS` should be for anything else. This isn't exactly enforced (i.e. most times you'd be ok mixing them) but could lead to potential problems if not followed.

> How does Redis treat values in the KEYS array?

The contents of `KEYS` are checked to verify that all keys are available to the Redis shard that's running the script. This mechanism is in place to allow running scripts in a Redis cluster deployment.

> What if, in my script, I have to use keys dynamically generated at run time?

See previous answers - that's doable but you'd going against the recommendations. Your script will be safe to run only on a stand alone Redis instance and since this behavior isn't specified, it may break in future releases.

Comment: Do you have any idea, how to handle multi key, which will be used in SORT command like `SORT mySet BY myHash:*->order GET myHash:*->name` ? Can I pass `myHash:*` or something like that?

Comment: @Schovi that doesn't seem to be related to this question & answer - please review the existing questions on Stack Overflow, or post a new one

Comment: Could you please explain more on "KEYS are checked to verify that all keys are available to the Redis shard that's running the script  yin a Redis cluster "  OR provide us some link what will happen when we use ARGV values itself as a key? And what is the drawback of dynamically creating keys during cluster environment. I am more worried on the statement "it may break in future releases.". Please help.

Comment: The KEYS mechanism ensures that a script can run on a given shard in the cluster - a CROSSSLOT error is raised if a key in KEYS doesn't hash to one of the executing shard's slots.

Comment: `Your script will be safe to run only on a stand alone Redis instance and since this behavior isn't specified, it may break in future releases.` This seems to severely limit the usefulness of lua scripts...