# Delete large number of keys in Redis

Tags: redis

I have a large number of simple keys to delete from Redis with a prefix and I am trying to find the most efficient way to do this atomically inside a transaction with Lua script:

1. Iterate with SCAN and DEL keys?
2. Iterate with SCAN and EXPIRE each key?
3. Iterate with SCAN and UNLINK keys?

Which of the above is the recommended way to proceed? Shall I have a different approach - like using a hash and multiple keys inside hash? Would any of the above be any problem in case of Redis cluster?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to go with `unlink` with batch processing like following and it will clear the memory in efficient way. I don't suggest expiry as redis will look 10times(this default configuration) within 1second to delete expired keys and it may not be efficient way.

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern 'prefix:*' | xargs -L 1000 redis-cli unlink
```

Comment: Not atomic, but I recommend this approach.

Comment: As far as I understand, there is no atomic way to delete all keys with one command and I have to deal with it in the application level - right?

Answer (score 1):

if your keys are simple strings, you can organise your prefixes inside hashes, with keys as name/value pairs.

Then, just drop the entire hash.

PS: Yes you have to rewrite all your read queries, but the performance impact should be negligible?
PS2: Doesn't address the clustered Redis problems.

Answer (score 0):

A Redis Lua script must be provided explicitly with all key names it touches via the KEYS array. All three approaches violate that principle as they fetch the key names with `SCAN`.

Comment: What can cause the violation of the principle? Is it a best practice that should be followed or something mandatory when using Redis Lua scripts?

Comment: It is a very strong recommendation and not following it may lead to unknown states. More at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089406/why-there-are-keys-and-argv-arrays-when-calling-redis-lua-scripts/32091333#32091333 for example.